# Is it a good pratice to put big Lists<T> on ASP.NET MVC sessions?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-3

Hell guys, I'm really confused about wich solution use for my project.
Well, I have a big List retrivied from my database(more than 1000 results with a large query clauses, searching in more than 3 tables with more than 3.000.000 items)  and I don't want make this query twice without changes because more than 300 users can make this big query at the same time, so I decided to use session to stay with every user query results, but I really don't know if it's a good pratice.
My team mate told me that's better make the big query at every user post because it's not a good pratice put Big Lists inside Sessions because a lot of users using Sessions with large Lists will waste more from our server than make this query a lot of times.
So, Is a good pratice put big Lists on ASP.NET MVC sessions?

**[EDIT]**

every user can have different results, they're not the same for all users.

**[EDIT 2]**

I need to show all the results of the query at the same time, so I can't paginate it.

Comment: Two things I always think about when I "encounter" a large data set... 1) Have you done any benchmarks to see if it is really a problem? and 2) Have you done all possible filtering to get the size to the smallest amount possible?

Comment: Are the query results different for every user? If not, then store them once for the application in the `Application` property.

Comment: Tim Rogers, every user can have different results, they're not the same for all users.

Comment: Bryan, today it's not a problem, but I'm thinking on the future, today I have 300 users, but I don't know tomorow, so I'm just searching the best way to display the results for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no, it is not a good practice to store large sets of data in the session...

The problem with storing "large" sets of information in the session state is that every time you do a form post-back, that session state is re-transmitted to the client, slowing down their user experience. (It's stored in a hidden field on the form, and can baloon in size due to poor compression of data to web-safe encrypted text - generally, you should avoid putting large amounts of data in the session state if you can)

In cases where the user has to view "large" sets of information, it's possible to create session-like stores or chaches to keep the info in server memory, and then just expose a session key in the session state; tie the server cashed item for that session to the session key and your set to re-transmit it if needed.

Something like (pseudocode)

```
Dictinary<Guid, DataSet> serverCache = new Dictionary<Guid, DataSet>;
This.ApplicationState.Add(serverCache, "DataCache");
// Add users session key and local cached data here
serverCache.Add(This.GetUserSessionGuid(), This.LoadData());
```

Also +1 to the post about paging this data - now that you have it in the server cache - you can handle paging easily.

All that said, keeping this data in a cache for some fixed time, might eat up your server memory pretty quick (usually "cheaply" solved with more memory... but still)

A good DataBase and Front end pairing should be optimized to handle the traffic load for the data. As suggested - do some metrics to find out if it's even an issue. I would suggest designing the database queries to allow for paging of data, so each view on the form by each user is further limited....

10 queries, one page at a time, for 1000 users, returning 100 rows, at a time (100-thousand rows, at a time with 1 query per user per second) is much more tollerable to a performance DB than 1 query, all at once, returning all 10000 rows, for 1000 users (1-Million rows, at a time)

Comment: "every time you do a form post-back, that session state is re-transmitted to the client" I didn't know that. So, Is it better make new query at every post?

Comment: There are times when it's not every time, but those are the exceptions (a good ajax implimentation doesn't do it every time, for example)... I go by a general rule, if the whole set of data cannot be viewed on a single page, don't save it in the session state. (Unless I'm using Silverlight with RIA / WCF, in which case, cram it in there! But that's a different topic alltogether)

So, yes, it's usually better to requery with each post.

Answer (score 3):

firstly- Bryan Crosby's remark is a very good one, plus- is the user going to need to view 1000 items at a time?
have you considered paging your data?

if, however, you decide that you *must* have that huge result set, then how about this-
if I understand you correctly, this query is identical for all 300 users.

if that's the case, the proper place for this result set is not `Session` but application's `Cache`.
this is because `Session` is per-user, and `Cache` is per-application (meaning- shared between all users).

so if you store your items in cache, once the first user has retrieved those items from storage, they'll be available to all subsequent users.

a few things to keep in mind, though:
1. since cache is common to all users, you must synchronize your access to it.
2. you need to set an expiry period (cache item has this option natively), so that those 1000s of items won't live in the memory of your application forever.
3. if those items can change, you need to invalidate the cache when they do, so the user doesn't view stale data.

good luck

Comment: sJhonny, every user can have different results, they're not the same for all users.

Comment: ok. what about paging? does the user need to view 1000 items at once?

Comment: I need to show all the results of the query at the same time. I can't paginate it because my users needs to see and compare these informations quickly, so the best way is using scroll. If I paginate it they'll navigate over the results slowly, so I can't use it.

Comment: why not use a grid with searching and filtering ability? for example- jqgrid http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html - see 'new in 3.5' -> integrated toolbar search. I'm insisting on the pagination issue because I know for a fact that nobody can comprehend 1000 lines of data at once, so there's no point in showing them all at once. give your user a convenient (and quick) way to get to the exact data that they want, without loading the whole of it.

Comment: Well, my grid rows have informations about a lot of clients, and I can have a lot of rows about the same client, and the problem is: if I paginate it I will lose agillity when I have results at the final rows of one page and at the beginning rows of the next page about the same cliente

Comment: you would also be losing agility if your website becomes slow because of heavy memory usage. In case you're completely against paging i'd suggest you take Bryan's remark to heart and hope for the best.

Comment: Well, today it's not a problem make every post these queries, but I'm thinking on the future, today I have 300 users, but I don't know tomorow, so I'm just searching the best way to display the results for a long time. EtherDragon said me that "every time you do a form post-back, that session state is re-transmitted to the client", if it is true and big sessions are bad things for the server, I think I'll really make the query every post.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't put anything that big into session if there's any way you can avoid it. If I did have to store it in session I wouldn't store the List object. Convert the List controls to an Array, and store the array if you must store it in session.

```
Session["mylist"] = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: A `List` just wraps an `Array`. What makes you say that storing an Array is better?

Comment: Because it doesn't have as much overhead. It won't make a huge difference, but in general it's a good idea to use the most lightweight container possible.

Answer (score -1):

Rality check: You have toy data.

1000 results are nothing, tables with 3 million items are nothing. They even wre nothing significant 10 years ago - today my mobilep hone handles that without a sweat.

Simple like that.

THAT SAID: it also goes the other way. 1000 items are a joke memory wise 8unless they are images) so they MAY be storage in session. Unless you run a ton of users, it may be worth to just store it in memory - there is a tradeof, but for example for most nitranet type applications this is doable.

My main problem with that is that session state is once possibly for multiple browser windows (tabls) and the number of times I ahve been pissed by a stupid prgorammer storing something in the session that killed me using 2-3 tabs on the site at the same time is higher than 0. I would be carefull with that. Like someone using two tabs for different searches to compare the list.